# Cannot keep method using proguard

Tags: java, java-me, proguard

I have a class, for example :

```
class GLxibPlayer
  implements Runnable
{
  AXprite sprite = new AXsprite;

  AXprite GetSprite()
  {
    return this.sprite;
  }
}
```

I want to keep method AXprite GetSprite() when using proguard. I tried using this configs :

```
-keep class GLxibPlayer implements java.lang.Runnable{
    AXprite GetSprite();
}
//
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class GLxibPlayer implements java.lang.Runnable{
  AXprite GetSprite();
}
```

But not working. Any idea? **[SOLVED]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess, based on an old version of proguard (you may want to confirm you're using the latest version):

```
-keep class **GLxibPlayer {
    AXprite GetSprite;
}

-keep class **AXprite { *; }
```

Adding the public modifier before the second "class" and/or "*;" at your discretion

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for your reply

I use Proguard version 4.3 as this is the one approved by my company (as higher version might having issue on some feature-phone).

I tried your suggestion, but the issue still exists.
Any idea?

Comment: Solved. The problem is on the previous process. The method already removed before go to Proguard.